# Не отображать картинку на малых экранах

Tags: css3, html5, media-queries

Такой вопрос: для экранов меньше 640px нужно задать display:none; определенному элементу.

Скрыть нужно img внутри тега figcaption. 
+ описанию (в тегах p) задать ширину 100%.

Я пробую написать так:

```
media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .slider-container>figure>figcaption>img{display:none;}
    .slider-container>figure>figcaption>p{width:100%}
}
```

Но, видимо, с указанием вложенности что-то у меня неправильно?
Не получается убрать изображение на малых экранах.
Подскажите, как исправить? 
Спасибо!

```css
#slider,
ul {
  height: 350px;
}

#slider {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 350px;
}

#slider li {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#slider ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 9000px;
  transition: left .13s linear;
  -moz-transition: left .13s linear;
  -o-transition: left .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: left .13s linear;
  margin-left: -55px;
  font-family: century gothic;
  color: #667;
}


/*** Content ***/

.slider-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.slider-container h4 {
  color: #0A7FAD;
  text-shadow: -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.slider-container p {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: -30px;
  padding-right: 65px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-weight: semi-bold;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 200px;
}


/*** target hooks ****/

@-webkit-keyframes slide-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  25% {
    left: -600px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    left: -600px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    left: -1200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    left: -1200px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72.5% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  75% {
    left: -1800px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  98% {
    left: -1800px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#slider ul {
  -webkit-animation: slide-animation 40s infinite;
}


/* use to paused the content on mouse over */

#slider ul:hover {
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #slider-container>figure>figcaption>img {
    display: none;
  }
  #slider-container>figure>figcaption>p {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3 style="line-height: 0.7;">Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5;">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 20px;"><br />
            <p>Сдается 1комн квартира &nbsp; м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="slider-container">
        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
        <figure>
          <a href="https://baseflat.ru/database.html">
            <h3 style="line-height: 0.7;">Однокомнатная кв</h3>
          </a>
          <h4>Ленсовета, 14</h4>
          <figcaption style="line-height: 0.5;">
            <img src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" style="float: right; margin-left: 20px;">
            <p>Сдается 1комн квартира &nbsp; м. Звездная, 5 минут пешком. 8 этаж в 17 этажном доме. Новая гарнитурная мебель. Бытовая техника. 23 000 рублей в месяц. Залог. + КУ</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверно потому что @media

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .slider-container>figure>figcaption>img {
    display: none;
  }
  .slider-container>figure>figcaption>p {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

Comment: Точно! Пропала @. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас slider-container это класс, а вы указываете его как id

возможно проблема в этом

те вот так написать попробуйте:

```
.slider-container>figure>figcaption>img{display:none;}
.slider-container>figure>figcaption>p{width:100%}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку. Глаз замылился :) Но, к сожалению, всё равно не получилось убрать img

Answer (score 0):

просто добавьте к картинке класс

```
<img class="hidden" src="https://baseflat.ru/Today-final.jpg" >
```

и напишите в css

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
       .hidden {
        display:none;
       }
 }
```